# CSS Horizontal Menu, Bottom Margin won't work

Tags: css

If you check out the menu here: http://blmp.it/syp/ the second row of the menu overlaps the first.

I made ul li margin: 35px, and it still won't get rid of the overlap!

Please help,

Comment: is the desired behavior just to get that last menu list item to appear lower?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use line-height on #menu ul li

```
#menu ul li {
    ...
    line-height: 50px;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the menu buttons to stretch across the screen I would wrap all the links with a div tag, then in the CSS for that tag add the following line:

```
width: 900px;
```

or just use 90%. I'd play around with it increasing the value until the menu stretches all the way.